# How to get read of django secret_key? is using get_random_secret_key() recommended?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am wondering if I can generate secret key inside my django application and assign it to the SECRET_KEY variable instead of reading it from the env variables?

```
# settings.py

from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key




SECRET_KEY = get_random_secret_key()
```

is it recommended or it is a bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would call `get_random_secret_key()` each time the settings are loaded, therefore setting a different `SECRET_KEY` every time, which is not good. [From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-SECRET_KEY):

> The secret key is used for:
>
> - All [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/) if you are using any other session backend than **django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache**, or are using the default
>   **[get_session_auth_hash()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.get_session_auth_hash)**.
> - All [messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/) if you are using **[CookieStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.storage.cookie.CookieStorage)** or **[FallbackStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage)**.
> - All **[PasswordResetView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView)** tokens.
> - Any usage of [cryptographic signing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signing/), unless a different key is provided.
>
> If you rotate your secret key, all of the above will be invalidated.
> Secret keys are not used for passwords of users and key rotation will
> not affect them.

Comment: why is it not good?

Comment: @AminBa The secret key is used for sessions, messages, password reset tokens and any cryptographic signing Django does. Rotating the key means invalidating all of these.

Answer (score 0):

Secret key provides cryptographic signing, If you rotate your secret key, all of the following will be invalidated (except passwords of users), so it is a bad practice to have them generated in each request.

> - All sessions if you are using any other session backend than
>   django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache, or are using the default
>   get_session_auth_hash().
> - All messages if you are using CookieStorage
>   or FallbackStorage.
> - All PasswordResetView tokens. Any usage of
>   cryptographic signing, unless a different key is provided.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-SECRET_KEY